# SSH won't set don't fragment bit

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, scp, mtu

I'm trying to send a file from an host through a gateway with an MTU of 552,using scp.
I expect the connection to halt since ssh should send packets with DF bit flag set, and the current MTU is too small.
Instead the packets are fragmented and the throughput is simply slowed down.Seeing from tcp dump of the host, the DF flag is not set.

Why this happens? Am I missing something?

I'm using Debian 20 if is useful, but this behaviour happens with other distros.

Comment: You do not say why do you expect the DF flag to be set. Normally it is not the `ssh` client who decides, DF flag is being set because of enabled PMTUD (path MTU discovery). Do you have PMTUD enabled? It is enabled by default. `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_no_pmtu_disc` shows zero when enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, the Linux kernel prefers to use Path MTU discovery to discover the MTU of the host and will therefore set the DF flag on IPv4 packets.  However, in your case, the MTU is 552 octets.  IPv4 requires that “hosts must be prepared to accept datagrams of up to 576 octets (whether they arrive whole or in fragments).”  This is because very tiny packets are inefficient.

As a consequence, almost every program using IPv4 can safely assume that a packet up to 576 octets (including headers) can be safely transmitted and handled regardless of the actual MTU.  This is essential for protocols like DNS which expect to send UDP datagrams and don't want them dropped just because someone used odd hardware with a tiny MTU.

Since your MTU is below the minimum threshold, Path MTU discovery won't always work, and some packets will end up needing to be fragmented.  The alternative is that these connections just wouldn't work in a lot of cases, which would be significantly less desirable and would make many people irritated, so that's not the implemented behavior.

Note that your MTU is also below the threshold for IPv6, which is 1280, and this link will not work at all for IPv6.

Comment: So the ICMP type:3 code 4 is sent only once, then the others packets are fragmented to mantain the functionality on the network,since the MTU is the minmum for IPv4?
So why here ( https://www.ateam-oracle.com/pmtud-importance-and-considerations) , in "Test 2" it claims that the connection hangs? I'm confused

Comment: In that particular case, the problem is that the ICMP packets that are part of Path MTU discovery are filtered (due to the network being misconfigured), so there's no way to determine that the sending MTU is too large and the packets are just dropped.  In your case, we know your MTU is too small to disable fragmentation, so we don't do that and don't use the DF flag as we normally would with Path MTU discovery.

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering
[Path MTU Discovery (PMTUD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery).

TCP packets have the DF flag set, which should cause an
"ICMP Fragmentation Needed"
packet to be returned if an intermediate router had to discard a packet
because it was too large.
The sender will then reduce its estimate of the connection's Path MTU
(Maximum Transmission Unit) and re-send in smaller segments.

If DF wasn't set, the sender would never know that it was sending segments
that are too large.

The only effect in your case of DF being set, is for the sender to reduce
the size of the packets it is sending. This does not block the transmission
from succeeding with a smaller MTU.